# SQL Server 2005 DateTime (return only hh:mm)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am working on a stored procedure which returns a column of `DateTime` datatype.

But I want to return only `hh:mm` with no seconds. I am using this but it returns seconds.

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), tbltime.Time, 108) AS [Time]
```

Any ideas to remove the seconds?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just change it to convert to VARCHAR(5) instead :)

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),tbltime.Time,108) AS [Time]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),getdate(),108),5)
```